# Including banner images on R markdown website pages

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

I'm developing a simple R-markdown website with multiple pages. Other than the home page, each page has a table of contents and content accordingly.

The yaml of such a page would be as follows

```
---
title: "Page Title"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    number_sections: false
---
```

The output HTML would have the table of contents on the left and the content on the right, with the title - "Page Title" printed out at the top of the content.

I now want to include a banner at the start of the content of each page, as the background of the title. In other words I want a banner image on each page overlayed by the title of the page. The images are stored locally in the file structure.

I followed this approach https://rpubs.com/thaufas/555157 but this is specific to a single page with a specified banner image. But I would like a more general approach using which I can include different images as banners on each page.

Comment: More appropriate tags would be `blogdown` and `hugo`. This has little to do with R specifically. Also, you might get a quicker answer if you share it in the [Discourse for Hugo community](https://discourse.gohugo.io)

Comment: @Aman (Disclaimer: I'm the main author of `blogdown` and maintainer of `rmarkdown`) The OP said it was "a simple R-markdown website", which means it's irrelevant to `blogdown` or `hugo`. The simple site refers to https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rmarkdown-site.html and it's not based on `blogdown` or `hugo`. @zstar: I believe this is achievable via CSS, but it would be easier for us to answer the question if you could provide a reproducible example first, so we could use your example as the base. I can provide a brief tip below, and I'm not sure if you'll be able to adapt it.

Comment: @YihuiXie, yikes sorry! That was a mistake on my part. I'll keep this in mind next time.

Comment: No worries. As I said, I could answer the question without a full example. My only concern is whether you would be able to apply the solution to your problem (if you can, I'll certainly be more than happy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the `class` or `id` of the page title. Normally, it should have the id `header`. Then define the background image for the `header` element. At last, include the CSS in your Rmd document, e.g.,

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
#header {
  background: url(https://linesteppers.com/tutorials/RMarkdown/img/BannerImage_TreeBlossoms_4470x3024.jpg);
  padding: .5em;
}
```
````

You could also include the CSS via the `css` option of `html_document`, but you would have to create a `.css` file for each `.Rmd` document. I used the `css` code chunk above, so you wouldn't need to create external `css` files.